# What is the difference between the remove() method and the update() method while remove a field form the documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregate-functions, compass

I want to remove a field from the document so let me know I have to use the remove() method or update() method with the $unset operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `update()` method with the `$unset` operator.

`remove()` is to delete document.

Comment: means update() is used to delete document and update() method is used to delete or remove fields

Comment: `remove()` = delete document. `update()` = set fields of document.